# Is there a way to write chunks with python to aws s3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The API I am building currently saves files from an endpoint to my EC2 instance. I want to save the files directly to an S3 but I am having trouble streaming the chunks to the S3. This is the original code:

```py
    def _get_file(self, id, values, current, count):
        msg = 'Downloading ID: {} de {}'.format(id, current, count)
        log.info(msg)

        for i in range(TRY_COUNT):
            try:
                r = self._session.get(values['url'], stream=True, timeout=TIMEOUT)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    with open(values['path_file'], 'wb') as f:
                        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                            f.write(chunk)
                if values['acuse']:
                    self._save_acuse(id, values['acuse'])
                return
            except exceptions.Timeout:
                log.debug('Timeout')
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(str(e))
                return
        msg = 'Timeout: {}'.format(id)
        log.error(msg)
        return
```

The modified program is creating the directories and files in the S3 bucket but the actual txt files have 0 bytes, so it's not writing the chunks to the S3 properly.

Is it even possible to stream the chunks to the S3? 
Or do I have to store the files in the EC2 and then upload them to the S3 bucket?

Comment: nowhere in the code snippet you share does it show writing anything to s3

Comment: This is the original code I am using, the S3 code is not really working.

Comment: how are we supposed to help you then if you don't share your s3 code?

Comment: This is the python code that is downloading the files and writing them via stream locally. I'll upload the S3 code in a sec if you want to look at it. I just don't think my approach is correct and wanted to see another take on it.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using Boto3 for interacting with S3.

In which case, use the `upload_fileobj` method of the S3 client. The method accepts any file-like object and will stream it into S3 eg::

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

with open('filename', 'rb') as data:
    s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'mybucket', 'mykey')
```

You can either download the file locally and store it before uploading into S3 or if the library you are using to download the file provides a file-like response object.

This example https://gist.github.com/obskyr/b9d4b4223e7eaf4eedcd9defabb34f13 provides a file-like wrapper for `requests` that you could then use to upload directly into S3.